# How to change the style of a shared module in the modules that are sharing it?

Tags: html, css, module, angular10

I have three modules A, B and C.

The module A is being shared by B and C.

The module A is using global CSS from app.component.css which is like

```
 .section-top-padding {
      padding-top: 11.25rem;
      padding-bottom: 4.0625rem;
    }
```

The html of module B is:

```
<app-module-A></app-module-A>
```

The html of module C is:

```
<app-module-A></app-module-A>
```

I want to change the css style in module B

```
.section-top-padding {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }
```

Similarly I want the style in module C like

```
.section-top-padding {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 4.0625rem;
    }
```

I have tried to change the css by using individual css of module B and C. But it is not working. How can I achieve that If I don't want to change the global CSS as it is being used by other modules also.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your modules will be sharing same container you could use [CSS :nth-of-type() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```css
app-module-A {
  padding-top: 11.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 4.0625rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
app-module-A:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
app-module-A:nth-of-type(3) {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 4.0625rem;
}
```

```html
<app-module-A></app-module-A>
<app-module-A></app-module-A>
<app-module-A></app-module-A>
```

Comment: My modules are not sharing the same component.

Comment: Then... tag your question with javascript. You'll get better answers